# Word 2013 can't display all pages

Tags: microsoft-word

When I cut and paste some pictures inside Word, suddenly the panel froze, however I could save it. After restarting, Word cannot display all the pages, it only show first 14/29 pages. I know the rest are still there because when you view it on other modes, you can see them. It just doesn't display them in the normal view. I have tried copy all and paste to another document, open it in safe mode, reinstall Office, email it to other computer and open it in Word 2013, none of these works. The Word Online can show full document, but some pictures cannot display, although open it in offline, all of the pictures (in first 14 pages) can be shown.

You can see my document in here: http://1drv.ms/1nIF9tV. It has lots of pictures, some equations. It is written in Vietnamese, but you can look at the format though.